# Error: cannot access zzbgl in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

following is my build gradle file for app. I am getting an error when building the project and the detailed error is:

error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

When I change versions of some packages another error pops up indicating multiple dex file error or other kind of errors similar to zzbgl.
Please help me with the perfect combination of the versions for below packages

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hypertrack.wintry_consumer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

//HyperTrack: HyperTrack library
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://hypertrack-android-sdk.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/'
    }
}

ext {
    supportVersion = '27.1.1'
    playServicesVersion = '16.0.0'
    butterKnifeVersion = '8.8.1'
    glideVersion = '3.7.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnifeVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnifeVersion"
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1"
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    //Google Direction Api: Displaying route from source-destination
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.7'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //HyperTrack: HyperTrack library
    implementation('com.hypertrack:android:0.7.39@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
//HyperTrack: FCM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes, there was an issue related to versions of firebase and google services. Solved, Thanks.